# Testing whether a list represents a set with no duplicates

Tags: prolog

The builtin predicate `setof/3` can be used to create an ordered list without duplicates.

Can I also use it to test whether a list represents a set with no duplicates? Like this?

```
no_duplicates(L) :- setof(_,_,L).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use it in exactly the way you describe.  BUT, You can use setof to determine if a list is a set if you ask it to iterate through your list for members, then check the set against the original.  If they have the same length, then all elements were unique.

```
no_duplicates(L) :-
    setof(X, member(X, L), Set), 
    length(Set, Len), 
    length(L, Len).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Your arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

If you are using SWI-Prolog you can use the predicate 
[`is_set/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_set/1) in the `lists` module.

Comment: Is there another way to check if I am not using swi prolog?